# Texture Coordinate from object in linked material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, linked-data, append

I have an object that is being linked into a new file (Object A). Object A has a material that uses the Texture Coordinate node, and uses the coordinates of a separate object in the same base file (Object B.)

When I link Object A into my new file, it still takes it's texture coordinates from Object B back in it's own file. If I link Object B in as well and make a proxy of it, it still references Object B back in the base file, not the proxy.

(Note that this is different from how drivers work. If I had Object B driving something on Object A, linked them both, and made a proxy of object B in the new file, the proxy then drives Object A in the new file.)

Is there any solution or workaround for this?